# DRF: Why does view return "<Response [200]>" rather than string?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def like_view(request, pk, destination): #destination is the user_id
    post = Posts.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if check_self_action(destination,post):
        print("self action!")
        return Response({"message","cannot like own post"})

    if post.is_expired == True:
        print("expired")
        return Response({"message","post expired"})

    liked = check_like(destination, post)

    if liked:
        post.likes.remove(destination)
    else:
        post.likes.add(destination) 

    return JsonResponse({"Message":f"Post {pk} successfully liked by {destination}"})
```

As you can see I expect a response of the form `{"Message":f"Post {pk} successfully liked by {destination}"}`

However, the response I get looks like this `<Response [200]>`

Can you see or suggest why I am not getting the response I expect?

Another clue might be that I have an almost identical view called `dislike_view` which gives me the exact response I expect. Here it is:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def dislike_view(request, pk, destination):

    post = Posts.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if post.is_expired == True:
        return Response({"message","post expired"})

    if check_self_action(destination,post):
        return Response({"message","cannot like own post"})

    disliked = check_dislike(destination, post)

    if disliked:
        post.dislikes.remove(destination)
    else:
        post.dislikes.add(destination) 

    return JsonResponse({"Message":f"Post {pk} successfully liked by {destination}"})
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonResponse` is a Django response class. Try using the DRF response class `from rest_framework.response import Response`

Link to docu: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid I have the same problem using the DRF response class, can you think of any other solutions?